# Масштабирование сайта ctrl + колесико мыши

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет, у меня такой вопрос:

Есть сайт: http://retsismos.com/
При масштабировании (ctrl + колесико мыши) все он нормально отображает (уменьшается), а есть сайт: http://www.mtsimb.com/ru/ и тут масштабирование не получается, подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону нужно идти?

Comment: Что значит, не получается? Существуют разные единицы измерения, абсолютные и относительные.

Comment: На первом сайте он как бы сужается, а на втором растягивается.

Comment: Может дело в css медиазапросах ?